# How does extended resolution p-simulate extended Frege?

Tags: reference-request, proof-complexity, resolution

I found a [slide](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/ResearchWeb/Caleidoscope/talkslides1.pdf) stating that "extended resolution and extended Frege p-simulate each other", without providing a proof. It's obvious that extended Frege p-simulates extended resolution, but the converse is not so obvious. I've performed extensive search on how it works but found nothing. So, are there literature that explain this p-simulation in detail? Thanks!

Comment: See Krajicek "Proof complexity" (Encyc. Math. Appl., Cambridge Univ Press), Lemma 5.8.3. The key is "the construction underlying Lemma 2.4.6".

Comment: I thought this was in the Cook&Reckhow paper, but can’t find it there. Anyway, the simulation is rather simple: you introduce extension variables for all subformulas of all formulas in the EF proof. Then each application of a Frege rule is a valid inference from  $O(1)$ of these extension axioms, and therefore can be simulated by $O(1)$ resolution inferences.